# what software or firefox plugin can anylize the color theme of website?

Tags: themes, color-theme

I am a web front designer , sometimes I see some very cool web sites with beatiful color themes , I want to get the colors's list of the website ,what software or firefox plugin can do this job ?

Answer (score 1):

I would either use the Inspect Element tool (right click) or install Firebug. Check the CSS or HTML for the colors. If you're confused, check out [w3schools.com](http://w3schools.com). (Google Chrome's Inspect Element is very much like Firebug, but better. Also, I have found Chrome to be more standards compliant (such as the CSS @print rules).)

Answer (score 1):

[Web Developer](http://chrispederick.com/work/web-developer/) for Chrome can generate an overview over the used colors on a website:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Even if something could run through and grab all the #tags from the HTML/CSS they will be meaningless to you in that there is no promise that the tags are even in use!

I suggest you do a print screen and paste the site into Photoshop or similar and then use the Color Picker tool to work out which color(s) you like!